# How to debug a connection failure between Jboss and eclipse debugger

Tags: eclipse, jboss, debugging, jvm, lsof

I have setup eclipse to attach to a local JVM. But when I try to do the same for a machine over the network I get "connection timed out exception".

How do I go about debugging this issue?

I tried:

lsof -i :8787 on the remote machine, and it appears that a java process is in fact listening on that port.

What else could be wrong and how to go about finding it. Please help.

Thank you.

Note: My JAVA_OPT looks like this on the remote machine.
JAVA_OPTS=”-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n $JAVA_OPTS”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers often have multiple NICs; you might add the hostname or IP of the remote interface you're using to your debugging options, like so: `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=HOSTNAME_OR_IP:8787,server=y,suspend=n`

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the TCP traffic with a program like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html). Perhaps it's some naming problem in DNS?

Comment: I guess I will keep that as the last option. I was looking for common configuration things that people miss that I should look for as a first effort. Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to connect by ip address instead of hostname, bypassing DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a firewall or routing issue. Try using telnet (or something similar) to try and open a connection to that port. If that times out, then you have a networking problem, not a programming one.