# Unable to start JBoss 7.1.1.Final in debug mode

Tags: jboss7.x, remote-debugging

I am trying to start JBoss 7.x in debug mode by uncommenting the JAVA_OPTS line in standalone.conf file. I see a very strange behaviour that JBoss does not start, it quits with the error " JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)" BIND problem. 
Has any one seen this issue. Port number is 8787 and when I do netstat I don't see anything running on 8787.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if `netstat | grep 8787` does not give any result, then you could try with `netstat -an | grep 8787` to see the state of all sockets.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the value of the JAVA_OPTS variable.

Point 1: the JAVA_OPTS can be found in two files : `run.conf` and `run.conf.bat`. It should be un-commented only in one place, otherwise you will get some error like 'multiple definition of JAVA_OPTS', or something like that.

Point 2: Accidentally, I hit the exact same error as you did - `JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)` - while following the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921406/11233118

setting address with *address=**HOSTNAME_OR_IP**:8787* is wrong. Use only `address=8787`. Don't know if that is the cause of your problem, but I got that error this way. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/516214/11233118 for detailed set-up information.