# starting JBoss with remote debugger - application does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss

**CONTEXT**:
 I use JBoss  5.1.0.GA. I deploy an app in the following way: I build all projects (goal: `clean install`) in Eclipse to produce an 
`.ear` file, then I copy the `.ear` file to  the `/deploy` folder in JBoss, then I run `bin/run.bat`. So far, everything works fine, as I can 
access the application in the browser.

Next, I want to do debugging. One important mention: **my JBoss server is standalone**; there is no entry in the Servers tab in eclipse. 
So I need to attach a REMOTE debugger.

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/516214/11233118  and https://maverikpro.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/remote-debug-a-web-application-using-eclipse/

**Steps that I followed:**

1. set the `JAVA_OPTS` variable, in `run.conf.bat` with
   `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"`

moreover, in run.bat, the JAVA_OPTS is echo-ed, and I see in the output that my settings are kept as above

2. In Eclipse, I create a new Debug configuration, named "debug", of type `Remote Java Application`, with port `8787` (as above, in JAVA_OPTS) and host `localhost`
3. I click the Debug button in Eclipse; In the Debug view, I can see an entry named debug[Remote Java Application]. Expanding the tree shows that 
   the Threads are running.
4. I add breakpoints in the code (the second link states clearly: "You can add break points dynamically"), I open the app in the browser, navigate to the
   corresponding screens, and **the application WILL NOT STOP when it reaches the breakpoint**. As a check, I have also added log statements, in the same block as 
   the line with the breakpoint. After re-deploying the app, I can see the log messages in the log files, which means I placed the breakpoints in the right place,
   but still the app will not stop and bring focus to eclipse, as expected.

Any ideas?

I also tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921406/11233118: using `address=HOSTNAME_OR_IP:8787` gives

  > ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
  >   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

when I run run.bat

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1920236/11233118 : I use the command `telnet localhost 8787`; when the eclipse debug[Remote Java Application] is started, it will not connect (which is normal), but when I close the debug configuration, telnet connects , meaning there is no problem with port 8787.

Comment: Is your remote debug configuration able to connect to JBoss? When you add breakpoints, are you getting checked signs?

Comment: I solved it. Accidentally, I had the 'Skip All Breakpoints' button pressed in Eclipse